# IsolatedStorage file names case sensitive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I've found something which is weird to me - files are downloaded from SkyDrive to shared/transfers/ directory. As I've checked in fact it's Shared/Transfers/ directory. But both methods:

```
ISF.GetFileNames("shared/transfers/")
ISF.DeleteFile("shared/transfers/myFile.txt");
```

work fine. Then I've started thinking and I've tried to create a file with such strings:

```
diRECtory/file.txt
directory/file.txt
directory/FiLE.txt
```

All three strings point at the same file (I'm working in debug mode on Device). Does it mean that files in IsolatedStorage are not case-sensitive? I've tried to find any remarks about that, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h2ws3ft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) site concerns Windows and says files are case-sensitive.
Does anybody know something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was in your question only. From the link you posted (its case insensitive and not case sensitive) -

> In the Windows operating system, isolated storage file and directory
>   names are **case-insensitive**. That is, if you create a file named
>   ThisFile.txt, and then create another file named THISFILE.TXT, only
>   one file is created. The file name keeps its original casing for
>   display purposes.